# Job scheduler not invoke

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

```
JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
job.setName("dummyJ");
job.setJobClass(NotificationCreater.class);

SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
trigger.setName("mn");
trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);

Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

i am using above code to schedule my activity in NotificationCreater.class but i get error message

error:-Unable to store Job with name: 'dummyJ' and group: 'DEFAULT', because one already exists with this identification.

Comment: Your error string gives you the exact reason - there is another scheduled job with the same name in the group.

Comment: @Richie i have only single scheduled job

Comment: Then try by changing the job name.

Comment: you might have run this code once when a job was scheduled in your pool. Is this an error which you are getting when you are re-running it?

Comment: @VaibhavShukla i tried this option also but gives error

Comment: If you change name and the problem still persists then this code probably gets executed more than once. Add breakpoint on this code and when it gets executed.

Comment: is your code executed only once since JVM is up?

Comment: When do you want your job to run ? I recommend using cron trigger but i guess that wouldn't be causing the error

Comment: @Richie i think you are right now how to delete job from pool

Comment: Yes, i also feel the same that this code might be executed more than once. From where do you execute this method? servlets? or main class?

Comment: @VaibhavShukla when form is load i want to run my job

Comment: @VaibhavShukla i am executing from servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using servlets, and want to run your job on application startup, I guess this is how you should proceed to achieve.

The Job Class

```
public class DummyJob{

public DummyJob() throws ParseException, SchedulerException {

JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
job.setName("dummyJ");
job.setJobClass(NotificationCreater.class);

SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
trigger.setName("mn");
trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);

Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
 }
}
```

The servlet

```
public class JobInitializerServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5102955939315248840L;

/**
 * Application logger to log info, debug, error messages.
 */
private static final Logger APP_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("appLogger");

/**
 * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig) Initializes DummyJob
 */
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    try {
        DummyJob scheduler = new DummyJob();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        APP_LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        APP_LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

}

And servlet Mapping

```
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>JobInitializerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>JobInitializerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.job.servlet.JobInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This will initiate the job as soon as you deploy or start your application. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the init method in Servlet to initialise and start of the schedule. You should also use the destroy method in Servlet to remove the scheduled job from the pool once you application is removed to avoid the same error happening during re-deployment. You can do something like **scheduler.unscheduleJob()** and **scheduler.shutdown()** to remove the job and stop the scheduler from destroy method.

Answer (score 0):

> trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);

The trigger is being set for the indefinite repeat counts.
Meaning, the trigger will be there in database forever.
And as a result, the job associated with the trigger would also exist in database
forever.

So, you executed your program for the first time and become glad to see it running.
You stopped the execution and had a coffee break.
You then come back and want to show this to your manager and @#$%@# BOOM #$%#$%#$5.

You trying to create the job and trigger with the name which are already in 
database. And scheduler will offcourse prevents you from doing this.

Solutions :

1. Wipe out all the data from the quartz database tables before you start the next execution of 
   program. OR
2. Don't use an indefinite trigger . Use a simple one . A one time execution or two or three but not ~. OR
3. Use RAMJobStore.